# Sharing a domain model between different software modules.

Tags: design-patterns, software-design, datamodel, design-principles

Consider the following situation.

Three apps A,B and C must cooperate together: A is an external, third party app while B and C are in-house apps (so we have control over B and C, not over A). B  replies to requests made by A, using both logics contained in C and B itself. Think about B as a layer between A and C.

There are some underlying common concepts that A,B and C understand and use.

Suppose the key task here is to decouple everything, so that if tomorrow we want to use A1 instead of A, all the interactions between B and C stay fixed (and, respectively if we want to use C1 instead of C, all the interactions between B and A stay fixed).

The question is about the datamodel design for B and C. Two solutions come to my mind:

1. **Shared datamodel**: we introduce a datamodel D in a different project. D contains the "in house" version of the common concepts and is used by B and C: an A-version of the concept is mapped to a D-version and can be used and understood by both B and C. If tomorrow we want to use A1 instead of A, we simply re-write the adapter. If instead we want to get rid of C, we write C1 using the common datamodel D.
2. **Replicated datamodel**: both B and C have its own version of the datamodel. We now have two adapters: one between A and B and one between B and C. If tomorrow we want to change either A or C then we rewrite the respective adapter.

Is there any best practice for dealing with this situation? Is there any alternative to 1. and 2.? Is there any intrinsic problem with either 1. and 2.?

**Edit**
Following request I'll try to give a more explicit example (of course everything here is fictional. Also forgive my horrible fantasy).

ACME ltd is a used car retail company, needing detailed information regarding every car bought and to-be resold. This process is outsourced, so they expose a simple DTO with two classes `ACME.CarInfoRequest` and `ACME.CarInfoResponse` (containing proper fields). In particular there is the business concept of `ACME.Car`.

ACME is outsourcing to INITECH inc, a car data provider. INITECH has a big and updated database containing car info and also features a live connection to the police records to check if the car is stolen. INITECH has one main app to interface with the customer and uses a different app to communicate with the police: the INIMAIN app and the INIPOLICE app. Both apps have the underlying concept of "Car".

The question is: should INITECH use a shared datamodel and let INIMAIN and INIPOLICE add it as a dependency or should implement mirrors in the two apps?
In other words the two solutions could be:

1) INITECH builds INIDATA project. INIDATA contains `INIDATA.Car` to represent the concept of "car". Both INIMAIN and INIPOLICE add INIDATA as a dependency and use the same `INIDATA.Car`. When INIMAIN and INIPOLICE speak about a "Car", no translation is required (as they both refers to the same `INIDATA.Car`). On the other hand, INIMAIN maps the info contained in `ACME.Car` into `INIDATA.Car` via an adapter.

2) INIMAIN has its own representation of `INIMAIN.Car` (and respectively INIPOLICE has `INIPOLICE.Car`). When INIMAIN wants INIPOLICE to ask the info about a car, first translates from `INIMAIN.Car` to `INIPOLICE.Car`. Then when INIPOLICE replies, INIMAIN translates everything back from `INIPOLICE.Car` to
`INIMAIN.Car`. Of course `ACME.Car` is still mapped into `INIMAIN.Car` via an adapter.

Hope it's more clear now (even if probably the example is awkward, again forgive my limited fantasy).

Comment: Your question is open to a couple of interpretations. It will help if you provide a more concrete example instead of using names such as `A`, `A1`, `B`, `B`, etc.

Comment: @CKing sure, will edit the question asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is: should INITECH use a shared datamodel and let INIMAIN and INIPOLICE add it as a dependency or should implement mirrors in the two apps

The answer to this question depends on the list of services that *INTECH* plans to provide to its customers.

1. If accessing police records is the only service that *INTECH* plans to provide its customers, it is only logical that both the `INIMAIN`  and `INIPOLICE` modules share a single `INDATA.car` domain model (since there is only one data model that needs to be supported i.e, the data model understood by the external police application that `INPOLICE` will speak to)
2. On the other hand, if  *INTECH* plans to provide more services such as insurance details of the car through the `CARINSURANCE` module that talks to external insurance data service, it would make more sense that `INPOLICE` and `CARINSURANCE` modules have their own data models that are modeled as per the external services they speak to (Police record external service and insurance record external service will usually have their own request model). In this case, *INTECH* should have `INDATA.PoliceCar` and `INDATA.InsuranceCar` data models and `INMAIN` would map`ACME.car` to either `INDATA.PoliceCar` or `INDATA.InsuranceCar` depending on what type of information is being requested by `ACME`

It all boils down to whether *INTECH* plans to provide a single service or multiple services to its customers. If this is difficult to determine in the near future, it would make more sense to stick to a single data model shared by `INPOLICE` and `INMAIN` rather than over-designing for  a use-case that *INTECH* might never ever encounter.